# In Yahoo! Pipes, how do I take a string from item.description and copy it to item.title?

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

Okay, so I already have a Pipe where I extracted the string I need from item.description, using the Loop and String Regex modules, and am emitting the results with the "emit results" option. Now, where do I go from here?

EDIT: Since an example was requested, here is one:

The item.title is "NBA Game: Lakers vs. Clippers" and the item.description is "The game went into overtime. The final score was 110-90." So the I'd like to extract "110-90" and copy it to the title, where it would then be "... Clippers (110-90)".

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1/ Put the score in "scorefield"**

Rename operator: [*item.description*] [*COPY AS*] [*scorefield*]

Regex operator : in [*scorefield*] replace [*.*\(([^)]+)\).**] with [*$1*]

**2/ Append  score to  item.title**

Regex operator  : in [*item.title*] replace [*($)*] with [*$1 ${scorefield}*]

---

Nota :

In the above lines the outside square brackets are to be omitted  unless noted otherwise

For complements :

http://beckism.com/2009/04/yahoo_pipes/

https://brooksbayne.wordpress.com/2009/01/11/using-regular-expressions-with-yahoo-pipes/