# How to update item's title with Yahoo Pipes?

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I use the feed with items like below:

```
<item xmlns:hhvac="http://hh.ru/spec/hhvac">
    <pubDate>2013-02-04T10:13:51.616+04:00</pubDate>
    <hhvac:creationTime>2013-02-04T10:13:51.616+04:00</hhvac:creationTime>
    <hhvac:vacancyId>6887864</hhvac:vacancyId>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link>http://example.com/vacancy/6887864</link>
    <description>Description</description>
    <hhvac:compensationFrom/><hhvac:compensationTo/>
    <hhvac:compensationCurrency/>
    <hhvac:areaName>New York</hhvac:areaName>
    <hhvac:employerId>12345</hhvac:employerId>
    <hhvac:employerName>Employer Name</hhvac:employerName>
</item>
```

I would like to replace item's title with value like `Employer Name: Title`. Firstly, I've tried just to add `Rename` method and indicated there (just to test) `item.title Rename item.hhvac:employerName`, but in results titles became named as `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` etc.
What it wrong with my approach?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932622/in-yahoo-pipes-how-do-i-take-a-string-from-item-description-and-copy-it-to-ite for tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Loop** module.  Then put a **String Builder** module in the middle of it. Put **item.hhvac:employerName** in the first field, click plus to get another field, put **:** in that field, click plus again to get another field, then put **item.title** in that field

Then put **item.title** as the value for "Assign results to:" (and check the radio button next to it).